# Javascript periodic HTML POST request asks for authentication

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, post, request

I implemented a simple PHP page that shows data live from an embedded device.
Javascript periodically sends POST request to a CGI script on server, and server answers with the requested data.

Problem is, I use Apache user/pass authentication on the webserver (including cgi-bin directory for security reasons).
When I load the page, browser asks for user/pass, and that's fine.
Issue is when login expires, but javascript keeps sending POST requests.
It prompts me for user/pass at every request, but since the requests are 500mS apart, I do not have the time to fullfill them.
This forces to quit the browser on desktop, and crashes the browser on mobile.

Is there a way to let javascript send requests only after a valid authentication?Or just stop sending them until user logs in?

Here some code extracts.

```
setInterval(refreshTelemetry, 500);

function refreshTelemetry()
{
    getTelemetry();
}


function getTelemetry()
{
    xmlrequest.open('POST', "cgi-bin/telemetry.php", true);
    xmlrequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    telemxhr.send("action=gettelemetry");
}
```

Thanks everybody in advance!

Comment: You could check the response value with JavaScript and clear or continue the setInterval function as needed. 1) Request data. 2) Is data connection? 3a) If FALSE, stop any previous interval, wait for TRUE. 3b) If TRUE, do things and stuff.